# Cauchy distribution for function random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I try to solve the following task and I'm not sure, if my solution is correct:

Consider a random variable $X$ with standard Cauchy distribution and density function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ What is the distribution of $$Y=\frac{1}{1+X^2}$$

What I thought so far:

Let $g(z):=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$, then $g(z)$ is measurable since it is continuous and the following holds
$E(Y)=E(g(X))=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)dx$
with $$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Then the distribution is $$F_Y =\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx=\frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would have thought $\Pr(Y \le 0)=0$ and $\Pr(Y \le 1)=1$.  Your expression seems to give $F_Y(0)=\frac12$ and $F_Y(1)=\frac34$

Comment: Indeed the formula for $F_Y$ at the end is *very* strange. What happens if you try to compute $P(Y\leqslant y)$ for some $y$ in $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Henry Hi, I don't understand why my approach is wrong (seeing $Y$ as a composition of measurable function and a random variable) and I don't know how to solve it else.

Comment: @Matriz: Try Did's suggestion of finding $\Pr(Y \le y)$ for $y in (0,1)$.  I suspect you may end up with an arcsine distribution

Comment: @Henry I don't know how to calculate this. I don't know how to handle a composition of random variable and a measurable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $\Pr(Y \le 0)=0$ and $\Pr(Y \le 1)=1$
- For $0 \lt y \lt 1$ you have $\Pr(Y \le y) = \Pr\left( \frac{1}{1+X^2} \le y\right) = \Pr\left( 1+X^2 \ge \frac1y\right) $ $= \Pr\left( X \le -\sqrt{\frac1y -1} \right) + \Pr\left( X \ge \sqrt{\frac1y -1} \right)$